# How to make javascript animation work a second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function that triggers an animation

```
function jumpAnimation() {
  $('.array__elem').each(function (index) {
    $(this).css({
      animation: `jump 1s ease-in-out`,
      'animation-delay': index * 0.05 + 's',
    });
  });
}
```

However, the function only works the first time I call it. The animation does not retrigger when I call the function again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the css, jump keyframes and example `.array__elem` html for testing?

Comment: Why an animation instead of two transitions?

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you, can't believe I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding for css, `` animation: `jump 1s infinite ease-in-out` ``

If that does not work, you can also try `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

so that should look like

```
function jumpAnimation() {
  $('.array__elem').each(function (index) {
    $(this).css({
      animation: `jump 1s infinite ease-in-out`,
      'animation-delay': index * 0.05 + 's',
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The animation shouldn't run infinitely, only when the function is called.

Comment: @BorisGrunwald I was saying put that in the js function